# How to copy the complete iceweasel (firefox) profile including sync

Tags: firefox, firefox-sync, iceweasel

I'm running debian linux with latest stable iceweasel.
As my old machine crashed, I'd like to copy all data including sync from the old home-dir to my new. But so sad - if copying the `.mozilla` folder, sync is **not** copied.
Have I missed a folder?

Answer (score 1):

Copying the profile should result in all bookmarks, saved passwords, tabs, etc being kept. However, the sync will need to be reconfigured. Hopefully you have the password/key in saved passwords.

If not, then at least you still have your profile. You could just do the email reset and then reset the server with all the info on your new profile.

If not (and you have another machine hooked up to the sync profile) use the sync new device method...

There would be huge security problems if merely copying the profile folder resulted in sync still working!

Comment: Dear Phillip, thank you for your answer. Indeed that was the way I did it already. I just hoped to find a more convenient way - of course not ignoring security issues.